# Should i Declare a UI Object as "final" to be able to access it?

Tags: java, android, variables, inheritance

i have the following situation:

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.createcharacter);
            //Referenciando Items do Layout
            Button voltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voltar);
            Button criar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.criar);
           final TextView nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        ...........
     criar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    if(portraitSelected == false)
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateCharacter.this, "Selecione um Avatar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(CreateCharacter.this, nome.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else if(nome.getText() == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateCharacter.this, "Digite um Nome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
.......
```

in order to access

> else if(nome.getText() == null)

im needing to declare it FINAL on the beginning of the onCreate() method, is it OK?
if its not, how should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it as `final` so that you can access it inside of the anonymous `View.OnClickListener` class. This is a limitation of [Java's flavor of closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Java), but there shouldn't be any major problems with making the reference `final`.

Short version: it's fine.

Comment: Thank YOU! i've done some java programming in the university, but in android im a bit dumb, learning now how things work. so ill declare all them as final, the problem is that in android dev guides they were'nt final. Thanks